# Laravel + Vue: button and modal component not show up in blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am working on the CRUD part of a Laravel app.

It is supposed that when the delete button of an entry is clicked, a modal show up and ask user to confirm delete the corresponding entry or not.

I tried to do this by defining 2 separate components - a delete button and a modal. I placed the button in the blade php.

It just didn't show up but the element is there in the html document of the page and there is no error.

This is my frontend code.

How to make it show up?

Thanks!

The blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    <btn-delete project="{{ $project }}"></btn-delete>
</div>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('btn-delete', require('./components/BtnDelete.vue'));
Vue.component('modal-delete', require('./components/ModalDelete.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

BtnDelete.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="showDeleteModal">delete</button>
      <modal-delete v-if="modal" @delete="deleteItem" 
                                 @close="closeDeleteModal"></modal-delete>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
         modal:false
      }
     },
    props: ['project'],
    methods: {
    showDeleteModal(){
        this.modal = true
     },
    closeDeleteModal(){
        this.modal = false
     },
     deleteItem() {
        alert("project : " + this.project);
     }
    }
  }
</script>
```

ModalDelete.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
           @click.prevent="$emit('close')">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
           @click.prevent="$emit('delete')">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there're some errors?

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: i think you should do this `<btn-delete :project="@{{ $project }}"></btn-delete>`

Comment: Thanks! but it got even worse. The whole page became blank.

Comment: did you get errors?

Comment: Still no error.

Comment: Are you running `npm run watch` in a terminal window? Are there any errors there?

Comment: I didn't but I just tried. Still no error.

Comment: rerun `php artisan serve` and execute `npm run watch` like @Peter said

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: what do you mean by *the element is there in the source of the page*, could you provide screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, I should be the html document. The btn-delete element is there. I use Chrome browser and saw the btn-delete element in it. I don't have enough privilege to upload picture here so it is difficult to show you.

Comment: when you inspect the page you see some elements like `<btn-delete project="{{ $project }}"></btn-delete>`?

Comment: yes, it is in the html document but didn't show up. When I tried :project="@{{ $project }} , all the elements are gone in the html.

Comment: you shouldn't see that, they are not compiled properly, your components are not registered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183272/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-anndexi99).